# agregar bloque de codigo html al inicio y final de pagina con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo una web realizada con php donde tengo un header.php (que contiene el header pero ademas el head de la web) y lo importo en cada uno de los otros archivos .php
Ahora estoy intentando hacer la misma web pero usando php solo para ajax y me gustaría también poder importar el inicio del documento (styles y algún script que se necesita cargar al inicio) y el final del documento (el resto de los scripts) con jQuery.
Espero haber sido claro con lo que busco

Comment: Sí. Tienes que usar `$.ajax()` y con el resultado hacer `$('body').prepend()` o `$('body').append()`.

Comment: Disculpame, podrias aclara como podria hacer para que desde $.ajax() pueda obtener el contenido de un archivo html? No logro darme cuenta

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el archivo HTML que cargas debe encontrarse en el mismo servidor que la página desde la que se llama la función `$.ajax()`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Pablo no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, sobre todo esto: *Ahora estoy intentando hacer la misma web pero usando php solo para ajax...* ¿qué quieres decir con eso?... Me da la impresión de que no necesitas Ajax para esto. ¿Acaso el contenido debe cambiar en base a algo que el usuario escriba en la página, debe buscar contenido dinámico en el servidor o algo así?

Comment: En la web tengo procesamiento de datos e intentaba usar php solo para eso. Actualmente tengo mucho php dentro de la web para mostrar el contenido como quiero y la idea era pasar todo eso a jquery y php solo para obtener los datos. Logre cargar archivos como me indicaron pero no logue que funcionara jquery (dentro del html que cargo, todo lo que sea jquery no se ejecuta).  La

Comment: La idea era reemplazar todas las vistas que actualmente son php por html+jquery

Comment: alomejor te falta hacer referencia a la biblioteca de jquery,por eso alomejor no te va,cuando ejecutas funciones de jquery.Este es el enlace CDN que debes poner en tu pagina:`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: jquery esta referenciado correctamente. Y funciona en toda la parte que se carga de "base", donde no funciona es en el bloque de código que agrego